# Dependency header not found for sub directory in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, onnxruntime

I have the following project structure

```bash
sandbox/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── external
│   └── test_pkg
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── cmake
│       │   └── FindOnnxruntime.cmake
│       ├── include
│       │   └── pkg
│       │       └── test.hpp
│       └── src
│           ├── main.cpp
│           └── test.cpp
├── include
│   └── sandbox
│       └── sandbox.hpp
└── src
    └── node.cpp
```

with `sandbox/external/test_pkg/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test_pkg VERSION 0.1.0)

set(lib_target_name ${PROJECT_NAME}) # name of the library created by this project

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/FindOnnxruntime.cmake)

message("onnx includes: ${onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("onnx libraries: ${onnxruntime_LIBRARIES}")

# setup based on GPU
set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 86)

include_directories(
    include
    ${onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${lib_target_name} SHARED
    src/test.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${lib_target_name}
    ${onnxruntime_LIBRARIES}
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
target_include_directories(${lib_target_name}
    PRIVATE

    # where the library itself will look for its internal headers
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include

    PUBLIC

    # where top-level project will look for the library's public headers
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>

    # where external projects will look for the library's public headers
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)

add_executable(test_main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_main
    ${lib_target_name}
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets"
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/pkg" # source directory
    DESTINATION "include" # target directory
    PATTERN "*.hpp" # select header files
)
```

`sandbox/external/test_pkg/cmake/FindOnnxruntime.cmake`

```
unset(onnxruntime_FOUND)
unset(onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS)
unset(onnxruntime_LIBRARIES)

set(onnxruntime_INSTALL_PATH "/opt/onnxruntime")

find_path(onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS NAMES onnxruntime_cxx_api.h
    PATHS "${onnxruntime_INSTALL_PATH}/include")
find_library(onnxruntime_LIBRARIES
    NAMES libonnxruntime.so
    PATHS "${onnxruntime_INSTALL_PATH}/lib")

set(onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS ${onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(onnxruntime_LIBRARIES ${onnxruntime_LIBRARIES})
if(onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS AND onnxruntime_LIBRARIES)
    set(onnxruntime_FOUND 1)
endif(onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS AND onnxruntime_LIBRARIES)
```

and top level `sandbox/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(sandbox)

add_subdirectory("external/test_pkg")

include_directories(
  include
  external/test_pkg/include
)

add_executable(sandbox_node src/node.cpp)

target_link_libraries(sandbox_node
  test_pkg
)
```

`test_pkg` project compiles fine standalone with cmake

When I use it as a subdirectory as above I get `external/test_pkg/include/pkg/test.hpp:1:10: fatal error: onnxruntime_cxx_api.h: No such file or directory 1 | #include <onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>`

What am I doing wrong here?